# PHP: переопределить ключи массива

Tags: php

Здравствуйте!

Есть массив:

```
$arr = array('one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five');
```

Я удалил произвольный ключ, например `unset($arr[1]);`

Наш массив теперь имеет вид:

```
Array
    (
     [0] => one
     [2] => three
     [3] => four
     [4] => five
    )
```

Как мне переопределить ключи массива, чтобы в не было числовых пропусков при удалении определенных ключей и одновременно сохранить порядок значений? В данном слуаче нужно получить:

```
Array
    (
     [0] => one
     [1] => three
     [2] => four
     [3] => five
    )
```

Спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$reindexed_array = array_values($old_array);
```

[array_values](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-values.php) - выбирает все значения массива